# How to handle bootstrap error in xcode 4.2,ios5.0

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, bootstrapping

I did two sample applications in ios.Both applications i have done using storyboard.Then after i did i copied the two classes of one application to another.Then i saved and compiled,it worked>But second time when i build the application and when i run that application,am getting error like this:

**Couldn't register BundleIdentifier.application name with the bootstrap server.Error:unknown
error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(gdb)**

How to resolve this error?Please give me some suggestions in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is that you are testing app in either simulator or device and suddenly change for another without stopping it.

For this you need to properly close app from navigator before moving for another ios selection.

if encounter this problem then restart xcode and simultor(also reset simulator).

Comment: Thanks for reply.I restarted the whole mac.Then it got worked.Thanks for the advice.